# Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: azure

At one point my Azure AD Services were working fine and not costing me a ton.  However I wanted to learn more, so I started playing around and reconfigured it.  The result is that it now is way too much money and I can't reset, or delete certain resources.

I've been slowly trying to delete various resources.  I have successfully deleted a handful, which of course makes AD not work.  However I am not able to delete the 'Virtual Network', and two 'Network interface's.  When I try they say I have to delete the resources using them.  I however can't find anything using them.

When I attempt to delete the 'Network Interface' it says is used by an existing resource (i.e. /subscriptions/[somekey]/resourceGroups/[somekey]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/[somekey]).  But I don't have a single Virtual Machine instance setup anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas how how to delete these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you no longer need a managed domain, you can delete an Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) instance. There's no option to turn off or temporarily disable an Azure AD DS managed domain. Deleting the Azure AD DS managed domain doesn't delete or otherwise adversely impact the Azure AD tenant.

**Delete the managed domain**

To delete an Azure AD DS managed domain, complete the following steps:

1. In the Azure portal, search for and select Azure AD Domain Services.
2. Select the name of your Azure AD DS managed domain, such as contoso.com.
3. On the Overview page, select Delete. To confirm the deletion, type the domain name of the managed domain again, then select Delete.

> It can take 15-20 minutes or more to delete the Azure AD DS managed
>   domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/delete-aadds